# Why are skipgram parameters defined in terms of two vectors

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

The parameters for a skipgram classifier are defined like this:

[image]

Why are there two separate vectors, `u` and `v`?

Answer (score 1):

They CAN be the same, and some recent work shows that it can be beneficial (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05859.pdf )

Now two reasons why they are not the same:

1. Word and context vocabularies can be different, for example when using positional contexts: I_-2 walked_-1 the dog_1 today_2. The is the input word, and the other four words are the context words. Thus the word matrix is $|V| \times d$ ($|V|$ is vocab size, $d$ is embedding dim), but the context matrix is $4|V| \times d$ if we use context windows of size 2.
2. Skip-gram was conceived in the context of neural networks as a simplified neural network. The input to the network is the observed word's embedding, a $d$ dimensional vector, and there is directly fed to the network's output layer. Each neuron in the output layer has $d$ weights for each of the input words $d$ components. And so we refer this to as context vectors or context embedding, but they're really just output layer weights in the extremely simplified neural network that Skip-gram uses.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand. So `u` and `v` are separate for the cases in which the word may appear before or after?

Comment: No, they don't have to be different, but they traditionally are for the two reasons I wrote. 1)  The context vocabulary 2) neural network heritage. Reason 2) is probably what you are looking for. v are the networks output layer weights. People just happen to call then context vectors or embeddings.

Comment: But why does it have to have size `2*d` and not only `d`?

Comment: If the word and context vocabularies are the same (as in the original paper and usually the case), both u and v have size d, not 2d.

Comment: Looking at your original question, I see you've used the letter theta, which usually denotes the set o parameters of the ENTIRE model. In that case, there are 2 * (V * d) parameters, which explains the 2d you're bringing up.